# RequireJS "require" conflicts with pure-JS "require". Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm trying to set up a script in JS using Node.JS and requireJS, as I need to get the script running on a webpage. When trying to setup requireJS to work with systeminformation (node module), it goes in conflicts with the "requires" inside sysinfo index.js file. i.e.:

I tried getting rid of every require inside of index.js, but I cannot do that as it gets way too complicated.
main.js

```js
    require(['systeminformation/lib/index'], function (systeminformation){});
```

All good here. Works as I want it to work
index.js

```js
    const lib_version = require ("../package.json")
```

Here, I get errors saying that the module package.json has not been loaded yet, but it is not a module.

I would like that requireJS would work only on my main.js script, without interfering with other files.
The main error I get from the browser console is

```js
    require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "nameHere" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
    https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (require.js:1436)
    at requirejs (require.js:1797)
    at index.js:24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, I just came across this issue right now. First of all, the `systeminformation` package is only intended to be used server side, so this module will not work on client side (web page). Due to security reasons, detailed information about the client machines are not allowed.

I know, this does not answer the general question but for this case, there will not be a solution, no matter how deep you try to modify the underlying systeminformation source code.

Comment: hey there, thanks for taking the time to answer after so long. that day i was just getting started on javascript and I did not have any idea that node-js and pure javascript were two different things. I still have to figure out a way tho, as I put the project on-hold. maybe when I'll resolve the issue i'll come back here to show how I did it